# How can I use CStringA and CStringW in VC6?

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-c++-6, cstring

How can I use the `CStringA` and `CStringW` explicitly instead of the `CString` in VC6?

Certainly `CStringA` should behave as `CString` in the ANSI mode, while `CStringW` should behave as `CString` in the UNICODE mode.

Comment: VC6? Wasn't that from when dinosaurs were still alive?

Comment: Haven't touched VC6 for years (and never really touched `CString`), but isn't `CString` just a macro mapped to `CStringA` or `CStringW` based on the Unicode setting in the project properties? What's your exact issue? Any error message? Also: Aren't you able to update to newer versions? E.g. by using the 2010 Express Edition?

Comment: um is's just a tiny project, still not so much need for the slow and complex VS20xx framework. it's a pity that CStringA and CStringW havn't been defined as we could imagine in this IDE

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having with using `CStringA` and `CStringW` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, actually i just want a ansi CString to be able to deal with the unicode types, like wchat_t[]. It seems CString can be converted from a LPWSTR but the other way fails. Then i use the CString -> _bstr_t -> LPWSTR way and works fine.